# How to label points in manhattan plot?

Tags: r, plot, label

I am using the [qqman](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qqman/index.html) package and have some questions about labeling in qqman package. I ran the below command in R:

```
manhattan(mydata, chr = "CHR", bp = "MAPINFO", p = "P.Value", snp = "SNP", col = c("blue4", "orange3"), chrlabs = NULL,suggestiveline = -log10(1e-05), genomewideline = -log10(5e-08), highlight =NULL, logp = TRUE )
```

And got the manhattan plot but I want to label all the points with the  `–log10(p) > 20` (which is on the y-axis) according to the column “Gene” in “mydata” file. This column (Gene) includes the gene names and not SNP coordinates (rs…). Should this column be as numeric or as character?